# ListViews inside TableLayout

Tags: android

I have posted the same question on google's android-developer's forum.
I am repeating here:

I have a TableLayout with one TableRow.
The first column/cell is a ListView. The second cell/column is a
TableLayout again which consists of 2 ListViews.

When i inflate the xml layout, everything looks fine and i have set of
adapters for each of the 3 ListViews.

I have added dummy elements into these lists via adapters and am able
to scroll up and down the list.

But the onItemClick is not getting triggered.

The following is my layout file -

```
   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/top_header"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <Button
                   android:text="Edit"
                   android:id="@+id/button1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           </Button>
           <TextView
                   android:text="dummy1"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:id="@+id/textView3"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:paddingLeft="25dip"
                   android:textSize="18dip">
           </TextView>
           <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button2"
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Cancel"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
           </Button>
           <TextView
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                   android:text="dummy2"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:id="@+id/textView4"
                   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:paddingRight="25dip"
                   android:textSize="18dip">
           </TextView>
   </RelativeLayout>

   <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:shrinkColumns="1">

       <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:divider="@android:color/black"
           android:dividerPadding="2dip">
           <ListView
                   android:id="@+id/listView1"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="0dip"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:clickable="true"
                   android:focusable="true"
                   >
           </ListView>
           <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
                   android:layout_width="0dip"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:shrinkColumns="1">
               <TextView
                   android:text="dummy3"
                   android:id="@+id/textView1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:padding="8dip"
                   android:textSize="18dip"
                   android:background="#ff238E23">
               </TextView>
               <ListView
                   android:id="@+id/listView2"
                   android:layout_height="0dip"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                           android:divider="@android:color/white"
                           android:dividerHeight="2dip"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:clickable="true"
                           android:focusable="true"
                   >
               </ListView>
               <TextView
                   android:text="dummy4"
                   android:textSize="18dip"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:id="@+id/textView2"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="#ff0000ff"
                   android:padding="8dip">
               </TextView>
               <ListView
                   android:id="@+id/listView3"
                   android:layout_height="0dip"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                           android:divider="@android:color/white"
                           android:dividerHeight="2dip"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:clickable="true"
                           android:focusable="true"
                   >
               </ListView>
           </TableLayout>
       </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>
```

And in the java file, i do

```
   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
   lv.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapterLeft(this));
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
```

{
                       @Override
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int arg2,
long arg3) {
                               Log.v("blah","arg2 " + arg2);
                               Log.v("blah","arg3 " + arg3);
                       }
               });

I do similar things for the remaining two lists R.id.listView2 and
R.id.listView4. They instantiate different adapters but nothing
drastically different.

I don't see the logs getting printed. Why am i unable to click on the
items and get the onClickItem listener get triggered? Even doing this
       lv.setFocusable(true);
       lv.setClickable(true);
does not help.

Any idea what's happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I should have asked before answering below, are you populating your listviews with content?  I guess what I'm asking is, can you see anything in your listviews when you try to click them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the ListView element isn't even visible, or it's height is zero.  If the ListViews aren't populated, then the height (because of wrap_content) would be zero, making them impossible to click.  As a test, set the height manually to 25sp and see if it makes a difference.

Edit:  You have to set the onclicklistener within the adapter.  Right now, the adapter-populated items have the focus, not the overall listview.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062803/capturing-click-on-a-custom-listview-in-android) as an example.

Comment: Another thing it could be is if you are populating content, the clicklisteners instantiated with the adapter are grabbing the click events, passing them to the populated items instead of the overall listview.

Comment: I am populating the listviews. I can see the content on the screen. I can even srcoll the list view. But when i click on the list item, they are neither highlighted nor does the onClick Listener gets triggered.